# Can not deploy a test project to MobileFirst server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I tried to follow a basic example from the developer site ([Creating First Hybrid Application](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/creating-your-first-hybrid-application/)), however i have not been able lo launch the development server successfully.

I am using Eclipse Luna with MobileFirst Studio plug-in 7.0 for Eclipse, Java 1.7 and running on Mac OS 10.9.5

When i'm launching the Worklight server it starts to load, but at 20% (more or less) the process stops moving and eventually the MobileFirst console from eclipse shows the error:

```
[2015-04-17 13:18:44] Starting build process: application 'Test', all environments 
[2015-04-17 13:18:51] Application 'Test' with all environments build finished.
[2015-04-17 13:18:51] Deploying application 'Test' with all environments to MobileFirst Server... 
[2015-04-17 13:20:28] Failed to deploy application 'Test' to MobileFirst Server: : Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
```

And the console output for the server is the following:

```
objc[60261]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.4/wlp-1.0.7.cl50420141121-1414) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_71-b14 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path serializer.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb-api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path activation.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jsr173_1.0_api.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path jaxb1-impl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/worklight-management-ui.war!/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.osgi.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/analytics/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/Test/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 1.047 seconds.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xml-apis.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path serializer.jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:/Users/jorgemorales/Developement/mobilefirstWorkspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/apps/analytics-service.war!/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/analytics-service/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application AnalyticsUI started in 5.124 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/worklightconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightConsole started in 6.248 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application Test started in 6.466 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://192.168.2.1:10080/worklightadmin/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application AnalyticsServices started in 13.256 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightServices started in 14.172 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
Socket operation timed out before it could be completed
```

As an annotation, I have been able to solve the warning about JavaLauncherHelper by using a different JVM (1.6), but the main error persists so i came back to the original JVM (1.7).

Have this happened to anyone?
Does anyone knows where I can get more information about this error? I have been searching at this site and the IBM forums.

Answer (score 1):

The Java error is known, and is between Java and Mac. It's got nothing to do with MobileFirst Platform.

The real issue, is the socket timeout:

> Socket operation timed out before it could be completed

Things to try:

- Update Java 7 to the latest public build of **Java 7** (not 8) then try again
- Kill the Java process then try again
- Make sure you do not have several IP address (via ifconfig); bind an address in Eclipse > Servers view > double-click on "MobileFirst Development Server" and change the host value

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I followed your instructions, however is the same result, the socket timeout is still there.